# Parse GeoObjects application flow IOS/Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, geolocation

I'm working on a prototype IOS/Swift application that tracks the user location on a map. It then uses a list of points from a Parse backend to show points of interest within a certain radius of the user.
Here is my question: I'm calling the Parse query for "proximity" objects during the "didUpdateUserLocation" method. So this is getting called every time the phone location changes (which is A LOT). Is this the proper place for this? It seems to me that after a few users were logged in and querying, the PARSE interaction limit would be hit within a few hours. Or maybe i don't understand how the request limit works.
Any tips?

This seems to have a side effect of closing any open callouts on any placed pins.  Every time the location is updated, callouts are all closed so the user cannot click on the detail of the callout.

Answer (score 0):

Your current setup is a bad idea. A user without an unlimited data plan will be very unhappy with you, and probably all the other users will be unhappy with the slowness of the device when off wi-fi.

You should check the location each time it's updated and limit requests to the server to when the update location is significantly far from the previous request location (that you should store as instance variables). You need to define significantly far, but probably 500m+

For the map pins, ideally you should check which pins you already have and don't change them, just get a list of the new items that you have from the new location that aren't already on the map and add them.